# Selecting a row in PHP and putting that data into a form/text fields

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have page which has a table and for each row a corresponding button. I am trying to select that specific row and place the data into the text fields of a form but, the query doesn't seem to be working. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks. Here's the code so far:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['add'])){
    unset($_POST['add']);

    $id =$_POST['bookID'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE book.bookID = $id";
    $query1 = $db->query($q);   
    $data = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);


    }
      ?>

    <form>

<form action = "basket.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php print($data['Title']); ?            >"/></p>

    </form>

    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add to Field" />     
    </form>
```

Comment: You are not error checking, i suspect you might be getting some notice about object to string conversion but not seeing it.

Comment: Further more, Where book.bookID is not needed, bookID will do in this case as you are not querying multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Change about i missed something.

```
 $db->query($q);
 $db->execute(); // this line is missing you have to execute

 $data = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // no point fetching both when you know the names.
```